# replace subscripts and superscripts with text equivalent

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to indicate each superscript in an existing word document with the ^ symbol. I also want to indicate subscripts by the underline character _.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a search for text formatted with a superscript (note search box is empty)
2. Replace the found text with itself (`^&`), adding `^^` in front of it.

[image]

Text should now look like:

[image]

The same can be done for subscript text, adding `_` in front of it